# C# covariance: classes with different interface signature

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, implicit-conversion

I have a base class with the following signature:

```
abstract class BaseClass<I, S>
```

Then I define a class with the following signature to extend the `BaseClass`:

```
class ExtendedClass<I> : BaseClass<I, int>
```

So, `ExtendedClass` sets the `S` generic type of the `BaseClass` with `int` argument. I am using the classes as it follows:

```
BaseClass<I, S> anInstance = new ExtendedClass<I>();
```

This throws the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type ExtendedClass to BaseClass

Some simplified context:

```
abstract class Analyzer<I, S>
{
    protected BaseClass<I, S> Run()
    {
        // implements some logic here, based their results different
        // extensions of BaseClass can be returned. This logic is 
        // simplified as the following.
        switch(some_logic_output)
        {
            case true: return new ExtendedClass<I>(){ /*some property settings*/ };
            case false: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the context in which the line of error appears.

Comment: What is `I` and `S` in the third snippet?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: `I` and `S` are provided by the user of the library which implements these functions. So, at compile time they are just `I` and `S`.

Comment: Extended class will always expect an int when providing values to a method or property, while BaseClass would not set that constraint (is less specific). If you are only outputting values, you can make the base class use `abstract class BaseClass<I, out S>` to signal contravariance.

Comment: Sorry, no covariance on abstract classses, only interfaces! https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/309955/why-covariance-is-forbidden-for-abstract-class-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify for the reference what `S` and `I` are. If you are outside the scope of the class:

```
BaseClass<SomeClass, int> anInstance = new ExtendedClass<SomeClass>();
```

If you are in the scope of the class

```
BaseClass<I, int> anInstance = new ExtendedClass<I>();
```

`S` is a name given for the generic type in the context of the `BaseClass`. It does not exist outside of it and when defining a reference as you did you must give the concrete type.

Comment: Please check the simplified context I provided in my updated question; how do you think generic type `S` can be set there while the function `Run` can return various extensions of base class each with different argument for `S` type.

Answer (score 3):

The second type parameter must be set to `int`:

```
BaseClass<I, int> anInstance = new ExtendedClass<I>();
```

Obviously, `I` also must be a concrete type or another type parameter in a generic class.